# Is there a usable editor for iOS icons? (not Pixelmator or Sketch)

Tags: image-editor, icon

I develop apps for iOS and other Apple platforms. I need an image editor to create icons: 1024x1024 pixels, ideally from vector tools in transparent layers. Pixelmator Pro and the current iteration of Sketch are completely unacceptable.

---

### What I’d like

I need something that stays in its lane: It creates bitmaps. It should afford layers, including vector layers (mathematical paths that get converted to pixels on output). Where is that tool?

---

### Rant←←←← Critique

(I've reduced my critique of the current state to "feature-brag," "2005 Powerpoint revival."

"Getting Started" tutorials — five starting points each leading to two easy pages of click-by-click instructions (many spelling-out three equivalents) to display an empty document — is a Bad Sign. So no, publisher, reciting one of the 4^30 paths is no rebuttal.

This is what I mean by "stay in your lane."

---

### What can I use to create incidental art?

Ideally, from commands that can move shapes, use consistent coordinate systems, pour a color into the counter of the letter O, and place the whole thing on a transparent background?

There's nothing obvious in the Mac App Store; maybe I'm overlooking a gem. Now that I've seen what's become of my go-to tools, I'm willing to pay real money.